# AJAX on Scroll doesn't work when toolbar loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use this code to get data from server while scrolling using jQuery AJAX:

```
 var pageIndex = 0;
 var pageCount;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (($(window).scrollTop()) == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        GetRecords();
    }
});
$(function () {
    GetRecords();
});
function GetRecords() {
    pageIndex++;
    if (pageIndex == 1 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
        $("#loader").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mainPage.aspx/GetImages",
            data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I add a toolbar to my browser (below of address bar) scroll
        method doesn't work any more.
How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to know why the toolbar breaks it if you don't show the code for the toolbar?

Comment: Do you mean a third-party toolbar? Which toolbar is it?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, an add-on in Firefox for example.

Comment: The space used by the toolbar is probably changing the height properties.

Comment: @Barmar I checked it, `$(window).height()`  changed .

Comment: @Barmar My problem is only with Firefox and IE , when I change the zoom level of Firefox to 80% it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition in if statement is never satisfied in your code.
Try to console log out something first to check if scroll is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

HI here is working example. Wrap in document ready function. if still not bubble. let me know what jquery version currently you using.This working example i am using jquery v1.2.3 in that example.

```js
  $('div').scroll(function(){
    alert("scroling");  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="overflow: scroll;height:150px;">
  aalskdjflkasjdflkasd
  a'lsdkfjlasjdf;la
  lkajsdflkjas;df
  <br>
  <br>ksdkf;kasd;lfk;asdkf;lasd
  <br>
  a;sdjflkasjdflkasd
  <br>
  asdf;lkasd;lfasd
  <br>
  a;sdjflasjdflkjaskdl
  <br>asdjflkajsdflkjasdlkf
  <br>
  asdfkjlaksdjflkjasdlkf
  asdljflkasdjflkas<br>
  alsdkfjlkasdjflasd
  <br>kaljdsflkjasdlkfjasdl
  <br>
</div>
```

**Note:**

### The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.11.0

Comment: @Mike please check my updated answer read the note at end of the answer. So it's something your scrolling is not worked. i mean you must need to set overflow auto on your main parent element. example on body tag.

Comment: my problem is only with Firefox and IE , when I change the zoom level of Firefox to 80% it will be OK.

Comment: @Mike `if (($(window).scrollTop()) == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) { }` why you using this statement. what approach you trying to pick in this statement.?

Comment: I want to loading data with AJAX on scroll

Comment: Do you want to set any height then will you need to get data.?I mean Example you want get on when window 80% scroll.?